# Cannot access node data from class

Tags: c++, class

I am making a class to represent a LCRS tree, and I'm having difficulty with my search function. Here's what I've got so far:

lcrs.h:

```
    using namespace std;
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>

    class node{
            public:
            int data;
            node *right;
            node *below;
    };

    class lcrs{
            public:
            int height;
            node *root;
            bool search(int);
            void print(lcrs);
            void insert(int);
            void del(int);

            lcrs()
             {
                    root = NULL;
            }
    };
```

And this is lcrs.cpp:

```
using namespace std;
#include "lcrs.h"

bool lcrs::search(int x)
{
        if(root == NULL)
                return false;
        else
        {
                if(root->data == x)
                        return true;
                else
                {
                while(right != NULL && below != NULL)
                {
                        if(right->data == x || below->data == x)
                                return true;
                }
                return false;
                }
        }
}
```

This is my error message:

```
    lcrs.cpp: In member function â€˜bool lcrs::search(int)â€™:
    lcrs.cpp:21:26: error: â€˜belowâ€™ was not declared in this scope
    lcrs.cpp:23:15: error: request for member â€˜dataâ€™ in â€˜std::rightâ€™, which is of non-class type â€˜std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)â€™
```

I understand that I cannot access members of "right" and "below" without first creating an object, but is there another way for me to access them? I'm simply trying to see what is in "data". I do not see how to do this without first instantiating a node.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since your lcrs::search() method is a member of the lcrs class and not a method in the node class, when accessing "right" or "below" you need to specify which node you are talking about, e.g. specify "root->right->data" or "root->below->data" rather than just "right->data" or "below->data".

Comment: @Jeremy But I want to check all of the nodes. How would I specify which nodes if I am unsure of how many nodes will be in this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this with recursion? You need to have your current node as a function argument.

Is this what you're trying to do (in pseudocode)?

```
search(int x, node* current)
    if node == NULL return false
    else
    if node->data == x return true
    else
        return search(x, node->right) || search(x, node->below);
```

Edit: You would call this by starting it with `search(x, root)`.

Comment: Yes, that was just what I've been looking for. It compiles! Now to see if it actually does what I want it to do.